# use useState to append string values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global

Hi I want to create a global variable in react but I would like to avoid it, so I created a component and want to store string data in it such as below:

```
export default function settings() {
const [stringData, setStringData] = useState("");
```

I want this state to concactnate input string. For example

```
setStringData("I am ");
setStringData(" a ");
setStringData("robot.");
```

When I retrieve stringData I want it to be printed as

```
I am
 a
robot.
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: `setStringData(stringData + '\n' + 'whatever')`

Answer (score 3):

When you calling `setStringData` it is the same as though you just assign a value to a variable, e.g. `stingData = 'asdf'` so if you need to concatenate strings you need to add the current value and the string you want to add, below you can find an example.

```
const [stringData, setStringData] = useState("");
setStringData(stringData + "Some Sting To Append!");
```

UPD: Based on the comments, showing an example with some listener.

```
const [stringData, setStringData] = useState("");

const addString = () => setStringData(stringData + " Clicked!");

return (<button onClick={addString}> Add Text </button>);
```

Comment: How can I call it from outside of this component ?

Comment: For example for numbers we can append with the following example https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-usestate-react-hooks-476794132bd0

Comment: Well, there is no way to call it outside the component, the idea is that it should be used inside the component. You can add a listener on input if you need to add the string from input, but this still will be inside the component. 

What is your goal eventually?

Comment: They are doing the same thing. You just need to specify a listener and call it in here.

Comment: I want to create a logging component so this logging component will be used to log data and that's why I want to concatenate string data.

Comment: Well, then you should use a function to log something, rather than a component. The idea of a component is to display some UI, I would advise you to create a function that does what you need. 
Also, why don't you just use `console.log` calls?

Comment: I can't use console.log because I want to parse strings at some time and fire an event

Comment: I would advise you to use some kind of provider that will have value in a context that you will be changing. Then the Provider can emit an event when needed and you could subscribe on its events.